# Understanding recursive calls and function calls

Tags: f#

After asking a [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32319/coding-functional-style-taking-longer-time-than-its-imperative-style) one of the users was kind enough to give me this answer I am having hard time understanding it.

```
member private this.MinMaxAlphaBeta (board : Board, isMin : bool, alpha : int, beta : int) : int =
    let point = this.BoardPoint (board)
    if point <> -2 then point
    else
        let UpdateAlphaBeta x alpha beta =
            match x with
            | 10 ->
                if isMin then
                    beta, alpha, beta
                else
                    alpha, alpha, beta
            | _ ->
                if isMin && x < beta then
                    x, alpha, x
                elif not isMin && x > alpha then
                    x, x, beta
                else
                    x, alpha, beta

        let rec loop x alpha beta i =
            if i > 8 then x
            else
                let x', alpha', beta' =
                    let x =
                        let b = Board (board)
                        if b.SetBoardBool i then
                            // NOTE : This is a _recursive_ call!
                            this.MinMaxAlphaBeta (b, not isMin, alpha, beta)
                        else 10

                    UpdateAlphaBeta x alpha beta

                let x_new =
                    if isMin then min x x' else max x x'

                loop x_new alpha' beta' (i + 1)

        let x_initial = 0
        loop x_initial alpha beta 0   // Start at the zero-th element.
```

1. `let UpdateAlphaBeta x alpha beta` how is this function returning its result to it caller?
2. `let rec loop x alpha beta i =` has another function `let x', alpha', beta'` where is it being called from?
3. `min x x' else max x x'` whats the difference between x and x'

Comment: So the x', alpha', beta' are being updated in UpdateAlphaBeta x alpha beta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. F# has implicit returns for the last line of a `let` so all of the marked lines are potential return values

   ```
   let UpdateAlphaBeta x alpha beta =
       match x with
       | 10 ->
           if isMin then
               beta, alpha, beta //return
           else
               alpha, alpha, beta //return
       | _ ->
           if isMin && x < beta then
               x, alpha, x //return
           elif not isMin && x > alpha then
               x, x, beta  //return
           else
               x, alpha, beta //return
   ```
2. let `x',alpha',beta'` is basically doing a complex version of `let a,b,c = 1,2,3`
3. `min x x'` is taking the minimum of `x` and the `x'` from 2)

Comment: So the x', alpha', beta' are being updated in UpdateAlphaBeta x alpha beta?

Comment: @Taufiq `x' ...` are assigned to the result of `UpdateAlphaBeta x ...`